# converting vector<cv::Point3f> to cv::Mat of type CV_32FC3

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, type-conversion, realsense

I am trying to convert a vector to cv::Mat in which it is a 2D matrix (640*480) with 3 channels each element in the 2D matrix is of type CV_32FC3 (three channels each referring to x, y, and z respectively).

```
n_rows = 480 and n_cols=640
```

I am not sure why `xyzMap = cv::Mat(xyzBuffer).reshape(3, 480);` ends up with an access violation exception 
[image]

```
vector<cv::Point3f> xyzBuffer;
```

also, when I use the other method for reshaping:

```
cv::Mat xyzBuffMat = cv::Mat(xyzBuffer.size(), 1, CV_32FC3);
    for (int i = 0; i < xyzBuffer.size(); i++) {
        xyzBuffMat.at<float>(i, 0, 0) = xyzBuffer[i].x;
        xyzBuffMat.at<float>(i, 0, 1) = xyzBuffer[i].y;
        xyzBuffMat.at<float>(i, 0, 2) = xyzBuffer[i].z;
    }

    xyzMap = xyzBuffMat.reshape(3, 480);
```

it also gives access violation pointing at the following line:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is working for me but the colors are so weird:

```
xyzMap = cv::Mat(xyzBuffer, true).reshape(3, 480);
```

Pay attention to the `true` flag.

Comment: colors are weird typically means wrong order of channels. What's the order in your vector? RGBRGBRGB..? OpenCV uses BGR ordering, so you might need a `cvtColor(xyzMap, xyzMap, CV_RGB2BGR);` afterwards. Please upload sample images for further suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are filling in the matrix incorrectly. There shouldn't be any need to resize. If you look at the method removeNoise() in DepthCamera.cpp, the (x,y,z) coordinates values are assigned using the following convention:

```
xyzMap.at<cv::Vec3f>(y, x)[0] = [x value];
xyzMap.at<cv::Vec3f>(y, x)[1] = [y value];
xyzMap.at<cv::Vec3f>(y, x)[2] = [z value];
```

Hope that resolves the problem.